# How to resolve Dynamic LINQ ParseException: "Identifier Expected"

Tags: parsing, lambda, export-to-excel, dynamic-linq, mvcjqgrid

I am getting generic error message System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException: Identifier expected.

What should I check in order to resolve it? The error isn't very detailed.

I did check the source and the selector params from the ParseLambda method and T-SQL they carry seems valid and execute fine in the SQL Management Studio.

```
 Server Error in '/' Application.
________________________________________
Identifier expected 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException: Identifier expected

Source Error: 
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below. 

Stack Trace: 

[ParseException: Identifier expected]
   System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ValidateToken(TokenId t, String errorMessage) in C:\Projects\EDgE\EDgE-EDGE_Parsippany\WebUI\DynamicQuery\Dynamic.cs:1952
   System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.GetIdentifier() in C:\Projects\EDgE\EDgE-EDGE_Parsippany\WebUI\DynamicQuery\Dynamic.cs:1941
   System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseNew() in C:\Projects\EDgE\EDgE-EDGE_Parsippany\WebUI\DynamicQuery\Dynamic.cs:1038
   System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseIdentifier() in C:\Projects\EDgE\EDgE-EDGE_Parsippany\WebUI\DynamicQuery\Dynamic.cs:966
   System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParsePrimaryStart() in C:\Projects\EDgE\EDgE-EDGE_Parsippany\WebUI\DynamicQuery\Dynamic.cs:867
   System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParsePrimary() in C:\Projects\EDgE\EDgE-EDGE_Parsippany\WebUI\DynamicQuery\Dynamic.cs:848
   System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseUnary() in C:\Projects\EDgE\EDgE-EDGE_Parsippany\WebUI\DynamicQuery\Dynamic.cs:844
   System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseMultiplicative() in C:\Projects\EDgE\EDgE-EDGE_Parsippany\WebUI\DynamicQuery\Dynamic.cs:798
   System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseAdditive() in C:\Projects\EDgE\EDgE-EDGE_Parsippany\WebUI\DynamicQuery\Dynamic.cs:771
   System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseComparison() in C:\Projects\EDgE\EDgE-EDGE_Parsippany\WebUI\DynamicQuery\Dynamic.cs:702
   System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseLogicalAnd() in C:\Projects\EDgE\EDgE-EDGE_Parsippany\WebUI\DynamicQuery\Dynamic.cs:689
   System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseLogicalOr() in C:\Projects\EDgE\EDgE-EDGE_Parsippany\WebUI\DynamicQuery\Dynamic.cs:676
   System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseExpression() in C:\Projects\EDgE\EDgE-EDGE_Parsippany\WebUI\DynamicQuery\Dynamic.cs:662
   System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.Parse(Type resultType) in C:\Projects\EDgE\EDgE-EDGE_Parsippany\WebUI\DynamicQuery\Dynamic.cs:629
   System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(ParameterExpression[] parameters, Type resultType, String expression, Object[] values) in C:\Projects\EDgE\EDgE-EDGE_Parsippany\WebUI\DynamicQuery\Dynamic.cs:166
   System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(Type itType, Type resultType, String expression, Object[] values) in C:\Projects\EDgE\EDgE-EDGE_Parsippany\WebUI\DynamicQuery\Dynamic.cs:161
   System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicQueryable.Select(IQueryable source, String selector, Object[] values) in C:\Projects\EDgE\EDgE-EDGE_Parsippany\WebUI\DynamicQuery\Dynamic.cs:34
   WebUI.Controllers.VoterController.ExportToExcel() in C:\Projects\EDgE\EDgE-EDGE_Parsippany\WebUI\Controllers\VoterController.cs:2288
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1.<WrapVoidAction>b__0(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +208
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   Castle.Proxies.ControllerActionInvokerProxy.InvokeActionMethod_callback(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +42
   Castle.Proxies.Invocations.ControllerActionInvoker_InvokeActionMethod.InvokeMethodOnTarget() +208
   Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed() +56
   Glimpse.Mvc3.Interceptor.InvokeActionMethodInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation) +408
   Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed() +94
   Castle.Proxies.ControllerActionInvokerProxy.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +222
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +263
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14() +19
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +191
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +343
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +116
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8970141
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184

________________________________________
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272
```

ParseException at line 1952:

[image: ParseException at line 1952]

Call Stack exception source:

[image]

Comment: The strange thing is that I am using Dynamic LINQ in several places in my application and I get the exception only at one place. The others work fine.

Comment: I think we need to see the code that leads up to the Select LINQ operator being called.

Comment: I am using the jQuery jqGrid Export to Excel function and it works fine most of the time. I attached the code fragment.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I don't know if this is Microsoft bug in the System.Linq.Dynamic library or misuse of SQL column alias names, but in this special case the parser fails:

```
 Select Col1 as First_Name, Col2 as Last_Name, col3 as 2012_P_Customer
 From MyTable
```

The System.Linq.Dynamic parser fails when parsing Col3 as 2012_P_Customer. It did not like the 2012 number as prefix.

When I changed it to  "col3 as P_Customer_2012 " it worked fine.

I knew that prefixing SQL column is a bad practice, but I did not know that the same is valid for the column alias.

Comment: I'd suspect that these names are being converted to properties/fields and they cannot start with a number.